# Linux noob: Need to backup 2 linux servers to a Windows share

Tags: linux, backup

I have 2 Gentoo Linux servers that currently use rsync to sync between each other to do backups.

I have a Windows box that is our real "backup server".

I have a share on the Windows box called "backups".

I want to backup (preferably using something like rsync that only backs up the changes and keeps an exact copy of what is on the Linux server) the Linux servers to the Windows share.

Things I've tried and failed at:

-Deltacopy (apparently can't do SSH, so I'm not sure how to get an rsync command in linux to connect to the deltacopy service/share on the Windows server.

-creating hidden samba shares on the Linux servers (created them, restarted samba, cannot connect to them)

I really need to get this working asap.  Any help is appreciated.  I'm happy to answer questions, just don't know where someone will go with this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Windows share is mountable, you could do something like:

```
mount.cifs '\\winserver\share1' /mnt/winbackup
```

(you may need to add arguments to that such as `-o user=winuser,uid=localuser,gid=localuser` etc., depending on your configuration/needs.  `man mount.cifs` for details.)

from there you can just:

```
rsync -auz --delete /backup/dir /mnt/winbackup
```

adjust rsync args and directories to your needs.

Comment: I apologize.  I had tried something similar using "mount smbfs -o" but it fails stating "cli_negprot: SMB signing is mandatory and we have disabled it."  I can't seem to get around this error.  The remote windows share is on a W2k8 domain controller.

Comment: [smbfs](http://www.samba.org/samba/smbfs/) != [cifs](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_utils).  Try it with `mount.cifs`.

Comment: and `mount.cifs` is part of [cifs-utils](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/net-fs/cifs-utils)

Comment: I'm guessing I have to install cifs-utils since it says "mount.cifs" not found.  However, I'm vary wary of doing anything to this server, since I would hate for something to go wrong.  It has samba shares on it, along with a user_private samba share for each user.  Will installing these cifs-utils break anything else or cause problems with the current samba that is running on the server?  If not, how do I install it?  I'm very sorry but I'm used to the simple "sudo apt-get" of debian...

Comment: It has been years since I used Gentoo, but it should go something like: `emerge --sync && emerge cifs-utils`.  Look [here](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=1) for a quick crash course on portage.  cifs-utils shouldn't cause any breakage with anything else on your system, particularly Samba, as the Samba team spun it off into a separate package.  Only way it could cause a problem, in this situation, is if the during the install you are prompted to uninstall another program in the process (which shouldn't be the case).

Comment: Also, `cifs-utils` is dependent on the cifs kernel module (`cifs.ko`).  This is built into newer kernels, but due to the highly customizable nature of Gentoo you may want to check to double check to make sure it is there.  `modinfo cifs` would be the command do do it.

Comment: Chad, Thank you for your help.  I ended up going another direction, but did get this to work per your instructions.  Thank you.